# How much time has passed between Twilight Watch and Last Watch?

Tags: night-watch-cycle, sergei-lukyanenko, last-watch

There appears to be a definite jump in time between the end of *Twilight Watch* and the beginning of *Last Watch*. Do we know how much time has passed?

IIRC, Nadya was three in *Twilight Watch*. I vaguely remember seeing her age mentioned in *Last Watch*, but cannot locate the passage.

Comment: Also, Edgar had gone a long way between Twilight Watch and Last Watch, it sure was more than a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, she is listed as being five years of age in chapter 1.

> К сожалению, нашу дочку не обманешь, будто вампиров не существует. Она их прекрасно видит. Еле-еле отучили громко высказываться в метро или троллейбусе: «Ма, па, глядите, а вон дядька-вампир!» Пассажиры-то ладно, спишут все на детские глупости, а перед вампирами как-то неудобно. Некоторые и на людей никогда не нападали, честно пьют донорскую кровь и ведут вполне благопристойную жизнь. **А тут посреди толпы пятилетняя малявка** тычет в тебя пальчиком и хохочет: «Дядька неживой, а ходит!»
>
> Unfortunately, our daughter can't be told a fib that vampires don't exist. She can see them perfectly well. We just barely taught her not to say it out-loud in the trolley-bus or a subway: "ma, pa, look, that guy is a vampire!". Passengers aren't an issue, they will think it's kids' play; but it's not nice to the vampires. Some never attack humans, rightfully *only* drink donated blood, and lead decent lives. **And here they have a 5 year old brat in the middle of the crowd** pointing fingers and laughing "this guy is not alive, but walking".

Since she was 3 in Twilight Watch, it means ~2 years passed.